# How to support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5

Tags: ios7, xcode5

is this the correct way?

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height==568.0) {

}
```

my main story board is set up as a iPhone 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see how your storyboard-made app works with the 4-inch display, you can press this helpful icon in the storyboard (the one all the way to the left):

[image]

This changes the display to 4-inch to see how it changes. If the display does not look how you want, learn how to use auto layout to manipulate your app's views.